# SQL Server taking variable as Column name

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE SPAnonymUserData 
 (
   @Table NVARCHAR (64),
   @Id INT,
   @Name nvarchar(255)
 ) AS 
   SET NOCOUNT ON; 
   DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000); 
   DECLARE @ParameterDefinition NVARCHAR(4000); 
   SELECT @ParameterDefinition = ' @IdParameter INT,
          @NameParameter nvarchar(255)';
   SELECT @SQL = N' insert into ' + @Table + '([Id],[Name])
   Values
         (' + CAST(@Id AS nvarchar(max)) + ',' + CAST(@Name AS nvarchar(max)) + ')';

 EXEC sp_executeSQL @SQL, @ParameterDefinition, @IdParameter = @Id, @Name=@Name;
```

If I give name "Name1", server is taking "Name1" as column name.... please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try inserting a single quote before and after the input data.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SPAnonymUserData 
(
    @Table NVARCHAR (64),
    @Id INT,
    @Name nvarchar(255)
) 
 AS 
 SET NOCOUNT ON; 
 DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000); 
 DECLARE @ParameterDefinition NVARCHAR(4000); 
 SELECT @ParameterDefinition = ' @IdParameter INT,
 @NameParameter nvarchar(255)';
 SELECT @SQL = N' insert into ' + @Table + '
( [Id], [Name] )
values
(' +
CAST(@Id AS nvarchar(max)) + ' , ''' + CAST(@ShopId AS nvarchar(max)) + ''' ) ';

EXEC sp_executeSQL @SQL, @ParameterDefinition, @IdParameter = @Id, @Name=@Name;
```

Comment: Thank you....one small doubt [ ''' + CAST(@Name AS nvarchar(max)) + '''] quote is required only for varchar,? because for INT its taking without any quote..

Comment: Yes, for inserting string values, you have to wrap data inside single quotes.